# Change backup folder from /var/backup to different/external-shared folder in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7, backup

I need to change my backup directory to some other directory which is different from Magento installation root directory. How can i do this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

Answer (score 0):

You need to override helper & it's function

**magento\vendor\magento\module-backup\Helper\Data.php**

```
public function getBackupsDir()
{
    return $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR)->getAbsolutePath('backups');
}
```

Instead of `backups` give ur folder name

How to override? http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-override-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-using-plugin-preference/

Comment: there are lots of solutions to avoid core files changes...

Comment: If u have better solution then please provide @MagenX

Comment: as there is not much information from OP, see my coment about bind mounting

Answer (score 0):

Helper-Data.php

```
public function getBackupDir()
{
return    $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR)->getAbsolutePath('backups');
}
```

Override Helper Data file

Comment: why he needs to override core files???